# How to add new attributes to a tag in XML file using XSLT?

Tags: batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add an attribute with static value with xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096951/add-an-attribute-with-static-value-with-xslt)

I have an XML file which I need to modify.
For example:
Say my XML has a form tag 
`<FORM name=""></FORM>`
Now say I want to put some extra info to this tag like
 `frame="frmName" frameby="name"`
Expected result of running batch file **OR** some XSLT

```
<FORM name="" frame="frmName" frameby="name" ></FORM>
```

**How can I do it using batch file?**
I am just a beginner so please try to be simple.
Thank you all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477209/how-to-replace-text-in-text-file-using-bat-file-script

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-enviro

Comment: Do you always expect <FORM name=""><FORM> in the input xml?

Comment: @Sergius No it can be any tag. I wrote FORM tag just for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using XSLT to modify the XML, as further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417649/modify-an-xml-node-using-ms-xslt-script)

EDIT

xlst solution

```
<xsl:template match="FORM">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:attribute name="name">frmName</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: yes I would like to use XSLT.+1 for your answer,let me test it before I could accept it.

Comment: I don't know what is going on here, could you please provide some simple answer specific to my question.

Comment: @mohit Could you elaborate? The answer give details how to solve the problem using different tool (XSLT vs batch file). How can I be more specific?

Comment: This is not working at all, it shows an exception on my browser saying "not well formed XML".I don't know what I am missing.Also I am trying to achieve something slightly different, please have a look at the question.

Comment: It would help if you would include the whole xml (the one the shows not well formed XML).

Comment: Hi, I have resolved that, I was missing a closing tag.But I am still looking for my actual problem.How to add a new attribute to my existing tag while displaying the previous attributes ?

Comment: <FORM name="frmName"/> this is what your code produces.        <FORM name="" frame="frmName" frameby="name" ></FORM> This is what I need. :(

Comment: Apply it again with different attribute name and value.

Comment: Hi, it worked but it removed all other nodes present in my XML, but I guess I can handle that. Many thanks.